# How to get the exception from a cancelled+interrupted callable submitted to an executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Consider the following code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
final CountDownLatch taskStarted = new CountDownLatch(1);
Future<String> future = executor.submit( new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public synchronized String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            taskStarted.countDown();
            this.wait( 60000 );
            return "foo";                   
        }
        catch( Exception iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside ) {
            iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside.printStackTrace();
            throw iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside;
        }
    }
});
assertTrue(taskStarted.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
try {
    future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    fail("Timeout expected.");
} catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
future.cancel(true); //mayInterruptIfRunning
//how to get iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside here?
```

Is there a way to get the `iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside` in the main thread after cancelling? Do I have to create my own executor?

**EDIT**:
Just to make clear no `ExecutionException` is thrown, but `TimeoutException`, which does not contain any cause. The `iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside` is a normal `InterruptedException`.

**EDIT2**:
A little clarification: The task is relatively simple. I want to be able to cancel the task if it runs too long. For this I need a get `call` with timeout, which throws an exception on timeout. Still I would welcome into my log an entry of a stacktrace which shows **WHERE** the task was cancelled. For that I would need this exception outside the `Callable`.

Comment: Who is throwing `iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside` from within the callable?

Comment: The future.cancel(true) will interrupt the thread in which the callable is running. So the "cancel" call is causing the exception inside the callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can help yourself with a customized `FutureTask`:

```
public class TracingFutureTask<T> extends FutureTask<T> {
    private Throwable trace;
    private boolean done;

    public TracingFutureTask(Callable<T> callable) {
        super(callable);
    }
    public TracingFutureTask(Runnable runnable, T result) {
        super(runnable, result);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { super.run(); }
        finally { synchronized(this) { done=true; notifyAll(); }}
    }

    @Override
    protected void setException(Throwable t) {
        trace=t;
        super.setException(t);
    }
    public synchronized Throwable getException() throws InterruptedException {
        while(!done) wait();
        return trace;
    }

    public synchronized Throwable getException(long timeout)
                        throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        for(long deadline = System.currentTimeMillis()+timeout, toWait=timeOut;
            !done; toWait = deadline-System.currentTimeMillis()) {

            if ( toWait <=0 ) throw new TimeoutException(
                              "Thread did not end in " + timeout + " milliseconds!" );
            wait(toWait);
        }
        return trace;
    }

    public static <V> TracingFutureTask<V> submit(Executor e, Callable<V> c) {
        TracingFutureTask<V> ft=new TracingFutureTask<>(c);
        e.execute(ft);
        return ft;
    }
    public static <V> TracingFutureTask<V> submit(Executor e, Runnable r, V v) {
        TracingFutureTask<V> ft=new TracingFutureTask<>(r, v);
        e.execute(ft);
        return ft;
    }
}
```

This tracks the exception additionally to the base class but unlike the base class it will remember it even when the job has been cancelled. That’s why there is an additional synchronization between the `run()` method and `getException()` as in the cancellation case the job can enter the cancelled state (which implies “done”) *before* the exception has been recorded, so we have to introduce our own `done` state with proper synchronization.

It can be used like:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
TracingFutureTask<String> future=TracingFutureTask.submit(executor, new Callable<String>(){
    @Override
    public synchronized String call() throws Exception {
        this.wait( 60000 );
        return "foo";                   
    }
});
try {
    future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    fail("Timeout expected.");
} catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(future.cancel(true)) {
    System.err.println("cancelled.");
    Throwable t = future.getException();
    if(t!=null) t.printStackTrace(System.err.append("cancellation caused "));
}
```

(derived from your example code)

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at so.TestCancel.main(TestCancel.java:69)
cancelled.
cancellation caused java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at so.TestCancel$1.call(TestCancel.java:64)
    at so.TestCancel$1.call(TestCancel.java:61)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at so.TracingFutureTask.run(TestCancel.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I tried the solution and it works. I like the solution, since my callable does not contain the exception storing mechanism. One thing I changed is to have a getException(long timeout) method, which waits for completion but also has a timeout. Since the whole question is about timeouts I thought this is neccessary. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: ExecutionException is not thrown from your TracingFutureTask in case if the Callable throws something. See my edit for test code.

Comment: Ok. With your static "submit" method works like it should. Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `ExecutionException` you are catching should wrap around your `iWant...` `Exception` when thrown.

You could add custom logic by checking the `Throwable` of your `ExecutionException` within your `catch` statement in the main thread:

```
// pseudo-code
if (e.getCause().[something, i.e. getMessage]) {
    // TODO something
}
```

**Note**

In your `call` implementation, you are `catch`ing and re-`throw`ing the same `Exception`, which doesn't make sense.

**Note II**

It doesn't really make sense to infer a timeout from *within* the callable's logic, although you could always programmatically calculate the time it takes to do something from start of `call` to end of `call`.

The whole point of the timeout and the `TimeoutException` is for the caller to decide this deferred task has taken too long.

In order to do so, you catch `TimeoutException` in your `catch` statement.

If you need to "decorate" your `TimeoutException` instead, with a specific cause that triggered the too long execution, you can either:

- programmatically calculate the time from start of `call` invocation to end of `call` invocation, and `throw` a custom `Exception` that will be wrapped up by the `ExecutionException` (very ugly), **or**
- Have your own deferred execution of each "sub-task" within the `call` method, and `throw` a custom `Exception` for any that times out

Comment: Edited my question and added the reason for the catch and rethrow. Please take a look at that. Just try the code.

Comment: @GáborLipták why would you want to catch a `TimeOutException` within the context of your `Callable` instead of the context invoking it?

Comment: The task is relatively simple. I want to be able to cancel the task if it runs too long. For this I need a "get" call with timeout, which throws an exception on timeout. Still I would welcome into my log an entry of a stacktrace which shows WHERE the task was cancelled. For that I would need this exception outside the callable.

Answer (score 1):

The Future.get() method is your only way to get any exceptions that are thrown from within your call().   So just add another `future.get();` after your `future.cancel(true)`.

Comment: A future.get() after the cancel(true) results in a java.util.concurrent.CancellationException.

Comment: Because thats the exception that was thrown.  If it was a different exception that would be the one you get.

Comment: What exception were you expecting?

Comment: @GáborLipták, check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--): `CancellationException` - if the computation was cancelled; 
`ExecutionException` - if the computation threw an exception

Comment: @JoseMartinez : No. Inside the callable there is no CancellationException. There is an InterruptedException. Try the code.

Comment: @harshtuna : nothing new. I know that. Thats what I have written above. After cancel CanellationException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on throw/catch you could carry exception from within Callable simply as an object (using synchronised shared state). Looks ugly but works.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final CountDownLatch taskStarted = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch taskCompleted = new CountDownLatch(1);  // <- to sync on task completion
    final Exception[] wasSomethingWrong = new Exception[1];      // <- not thread safe, but works here  
    Future<String> future = executor.submit( new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public synchronized String call() throws Exception {
            try {
                taskStarted.countDown();
                this.wait( 60000 );
            }
            catch( Exception iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside ) {
                wasSomethingWrong[0] = iWantToGetThisExceptionOutside; // <-
            } finally {
                taskCompleted.countDown();  // <- 
            }
            return "foo";
        }
    });
    assertTrue(taskStarted.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    try {
        future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        fail("Timeout expected.");
    } catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    future.cancel(true); //mayInterruptIfRunning
    taskCompleted.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // <- sync

    assertNotNull(wasSomethingWrong[0]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wasSomethingWrong[0].getStackTrace()));
    assertEquals(InterruptedException.class, wasSomethingWrong[0].getClass());  // <- PROFIT
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I thought about as a workaround. You have got one point, but it is far from being ideal, as you have also written :)